# How can I utilize AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion in order to use external libraries in my AWS Lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-sam-cli

I need to use external library that is located on my local file system in order to successfully execute my Lambda function. Using AWS SAM framework I found out that this can be done by specifying `AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion` resource.

What I am not sure is how does this exactly work and how do I specify path to my external library. Do I first need to deploy my external library to S3 bucket or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deploy the jar on layer in AWS Lambda layers section

> AWS Lambda Layers :
>
> You can configure your Lambda function to pull in
> additional code and content in the form of layers. A layer is a ZIP
> archive that contains libraries, a custom runtime, or other
> dependencies. With layers, you can use libraries in your function
> without needing to include them in your deployment package.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Following are the steps to use AWS lambda layers

- Write a Lambda layer code
- Package Lambda layer
- Deploy Lambda layer
- Attached a layer to function Call a method
- Verify the results

Once you complete writing your function make sure the pom.xml contains the artifacts and maven-shade-plugin

```
<groupId>java-lambda-layer</groupId>
<artifactId>java-lambda-layer</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build> 
<plugins> 
<plugin> 
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId> 
<version>2.3</version> 
<configuration> <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom> </configuration> 
<executions> 
<execution> 
<phase>package</phase> 
<goals> 
<goal>shade</goal> 
</goals> 
</execution> 
</executions> 
</plugin> 
</plugins> 
</build>
```

Run Maven

```
 mvnclean install and package
```

Please read further on following link

- https://medium.com/@zeebaig/working-with-aws-lambda-layers-ddf5c91674d3